# Communication between Devops pipelines and Self hosted build agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

When a DevOps organization/Pipelines and a self-hosted agent on a virtual machine (VM) in the cloud are in the same region, is the connection established via the private Microsoft backbone network?

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#outbound-connections

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#communication-with-azure-pipelines

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, the pipeline and self-hosted agent communicate through the public network, even if your organization and Azure VM are in the same region. According to this official doc [Allowed IP addresses and domain URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4), there are only outbound connections and inbound connections used in different scenarios without any private network mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default all communication between the agent and Azure DevOps will be routed over public infrastructure.

[To tunnel your traffic across private networks, you need to setup ExpressRoute for Azure Devops](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/expressroute-for-azure-devops/).